# How to loop my function based on query result

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a function which makes a random id `makeid();` Just to ensure the id is unique I have a SQL statement which checks if the id already exists.

```
$does_id_exist = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM signups WHERE affid='$affid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($does_id_exist) == 1) 
  { 
  #loop function and perform query again
  }
else
  {
  #insert record
  }
```

So I'm having trouble with looping the function. How do I loop my function `makeid()` and perform the `$does_id_exist` check to ensure that each `ID` is unique.

--UPDATE-- Just to clarify- My code makes an id like `YES@281E` But before I INSERT this id into the users record. I just need to verify IF any other user already has this id. IF another user has this id that event must trigger my function to create a new id e.g. `WOW!29E3` and again check the sql/query to ensure no other user has *that id*. Continue to loop if fails or end and INSERT if the id is available.

Comment: You could always use an auto-incrementing ID field and sidestep this completely.

Comment: No i cant because this generates something like an affiliate id. It's not an INT -- its a word + some random numbers and + a symbol.

Comment: You should be escaping your SQL using [placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid serious SQL injection bugs. If you're working on a new application, please **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` since it is outdated and dangerous. `mysqli` and PDO are much safer and easier to use properly.

Comment: @tadman I am aware this isn't production code. Personal testing and I'm in the process of switching to prepared statement `PDO` ty

Comment: Good to hear. This kind of query is radioactively hazardous and should be switched out as soon as you can. I suppose there's a kind of irony that someone with your username would have code with SQL injection bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either just use a primary key on your database table, or something like this:

```
<?php
    // the id to insert
    $newId = null;

    // populate with results from a SELECT `aff_id` FROM `table`
    $currentIds = array(); 

    // prepopulate
    for( $i=0; $i<100000; $i++ )
    {
        $currentIds[] = "STRING_" + rand();
    }

    // generate at least one id
    do
    {
        $newId = "STRING_" + rand();
    }
    // while the id is taken (cached in $currentIds)
    while( in_array($newId, $currentIds) );

    // when we get here, we have an id that's not taken.
    echo $newId;    
?>
```

Output:

> STRING_905649971 (run time 95ms);

I'd definitely not recommend running the query repeatedly. Perhaps a final check before you insert, if your traffic volume is high enough.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My code makes an id like *YES@281E* But before I INSERT this id into the users record. I just need to verify if any other user already has this id. IF another user has this id that event must trigger my function to create a new id *WOW!29E3* and again check the query to ensure no other user has that id. CONTINUE TO LOOP IF FAILS or end and INSERT if the id is available.

Comment: @FA''''''''''''''''''''''': That's exactly what it does. You'll populate `$currentIds` with the current ids taken, then generate a new one (`do`) while (`while`) the current one is taken, ie: is in (`in_array`) the current ids. I then note that you can do a quick `SELECT COUNT(*)` before you do the final insert, just incase someone else has made the ID and it wasn't cached into `$currentIds`.

Comment: I like the count for cache proofing - but I cant pull all the id's as an array that doesn't make sense. There are over 40,000 ids -- I need to just verify that the one I just generated is unique before inserting and count it to cache proof like u said. Can you please revise your answer.

Comment: @FA''''''''''''''''''''''': I've updated my example to populate an array with one hundred thousand random ids. The whole thing takes less than a second (including random propogation). Unless your ids are 1000 chars long, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hey that's cool -- How did you get that runtime..? The ids are <12 chars long. Thank you for your help but can you please explain why you insist on pulling an array when I can just check that 1 field? I mean your example will work for now, but what if the db held 50m records. Doesn't it make more sense to just check for the id instead of load an array of every id in the DB? Im curious on the run time of my theory to yours and im willing to guess its under 20ms

Comment: I use an app for OSX called [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/) to run all sample code I contribute to SO. It profiles automagically. And, if you want to select from the DB you can, but there will be a lot more overhead, as you'll be doing lots of queries, potentially.

Answer (score -1):

Do not do `COUNT(*)`, because you do not need to know how many rows is there (it should be 0 or 1 as you need Id unique), so even DB finds your row it will still be checking for the whole table to count. You really care if you got 1 row, so just select for row with that ID and this sufficient. You should also avoid using `rand()` - this does not help as you see and you cannot predict how many loops you can do before you find "free slot". use something predictable, like date prefix, or prefix **incremented** each day. anything that would help you narrow the data set. But for now (pseudocode!):

```
$id = null;
while( $id == null ) {
  $newId = 'prefix' . rand();

  mysql_query("SELECT `affid` FROM `signups` WHERE `affid`='${newId}'");
  if( mysql_num_rows() == 0) {
    $id = newId;
    break;
  } 
}
```

Ensure you got DB indexed, to speed things up.

EDIT: I do agree that any cache would be useful to speed things up (you can add it easily yourself based on @Josh example), still, I think this is fixing at wrong place. If possible rethink the way you generate your ID. It does not really need to be auto increment, but something more predictable than `rand()` would help you. If your ID does not need to be easily memorable and it is not any security concern to have them sequential, maybe use numbers with other base than 10 (i.e. using 26 would use all digits + letters so you'd end with `PREFIX-AX3TK`, so string as you want, and at the same time you would easily be able to quickly generate next Id

Comment: That's not a very efficient recommendation. He should pre-cache the taken IDs in an array, as my example does, and IF his site is high volume enough that concurrent IDs are being generated, then do one last SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE ID=$NEW. That way it's just 1-2 queries, as opposed to `N` for each collision.

Comment: Sure, "cache" in array wouldn't hurt. thanks for -1. quite childish

Comment: @FA''''''''''''''''''''''' I was taking to Josh, not you. And no, I did not downvote anything in this question, so you was not hit by me.

Comment: I'm trying to use your example. I find it more suitable. If I can get it to work I will upvote and check your answer. Thx